# Creating custom access modifiers in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm sure this is probably impossible, as it seems someone else would have done it already, but is there any way to create custom access modifiers in Java?

I really dislike having a bunch of getters for a variable when I want it to be read-only to other classes, and it seems like there should be some way to work around this, but I've found nothing useful by searching.

Comment: Use interfaces, present the "readonly" or "immutable" interface to those who do not need access and the "writable"/"mutable" interface to those who do...

Comment: But that's exactly what `getters` does, just read the instance variables. They can't modify it. To modify an instance variable, we use `setter` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define new language-level access modifiers.

### Possible solutions

- The preferred, easiest way is to use interfaces: create multiple interfaces containing only the methods you want to publish to different clients (objects). Have your object implement all, and only pass your object as the reference of the interface you want to publish it as.
- If you want more control and more security, use the [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) and define proper [permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Permission.html).
- Another solution is AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming, e.g. [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ)).
- A custom, much lighter solution (compared to AOP) based on *"access"* keys is presented below.

### Custom Access Based on Keys

The object to which you want to restrict access could create an internal key (the *"access"* key). Any other object it wants to grant access can share this key explicitly, e.g. by calling their method and passing the key.

Now the method you want to *"guard"* would also take an additional parameter (the key), and if the caller can't provide the key, you can simply throw an `Exception`.

Here is a demonstration:

```
public class Service {
    private final Object accessKey = new Object();

    public Service() {
        // Here we provide access to some object:
        someObject.receiveAccessKey(accessKey);
    }

    public void service(Object accessKey) {
        if (this.accessKey != accessKey)
            throw new RejectedExecutionException();
        System.out.println("Access granted, executing...");
    }

}
```

You can also modify this pattern so that you pass the access key to the constructor, and that way you can decide who you give the access key to.

It is also up to your consideration whether you want to throw a `RuntimeException` (which callers are not required to catch), or a non-runtime exception which callers must catch in a `try-catch` block (or declare to throw it). In this example I used a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict access to field or method by using aspect oriented programming (cf: aspectJ)

You can add a joinpoint on all you setter and in the before advice throw an exception when it's coming from another class.

But this add a great lot of complexity to your apps and you should really think about it before going that way.

As you thought, you cannot restrict the visibility, but you can restrict the access in that way.

*precision on the setter joinpoint: it can intercept setting a value directly to a class field, you doesn't have to have an actual setter method.

Answer (score 0):

An option for is: `Reflection`
you can use it access fields dynamically.

Comment: [_and now you have two problems..._](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247#comment-3085) :)